# How to have citations individually bracketed with biblatex-ieee

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `biblatex` with the `biblatex-ieee` style and I've run into a problem with the formatting of citations in a group.  For example, I can use:

```
This is two citations~\cite{ref1,ref2}.  This is three citations~\cite{ref3,ref4,ref5}.
```

According to IEEE style, this should yield:

> This is two citations [1], [2].  This is three citations [3]–[5].

Instead, what is actually produced is:

> This is two citations [1, 2].  This is three citations [3–5].

In `numeric-comp.cbx` (referenced by `ieee.cbx`), there is a line saying `\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\space}`, but I don't see how I would modify this to close provide "`], [`" in one case and "`]–[`" in the case of several citations.  Of course, I don't see from this line how `biblatex` knows to transform `\addcomma` to a dash in the first place, so I might be looking in the wrong place altogether.

Could someone guide me on how to adjust things to obtain the first example?

Comment: Which version of `biblatex-ieee` do you have? I remember this issue, and according to the log it _should_ be fixed in v1.1a.

Comment: Hi Joseph, I'm using 1.1d, according to `ieee.cbx` and `ieee.bbx`.  They have `2012/10/12 v1.1d biblatex bibliography style` at the beginning.  If it matters, this is with `biblatex` 2.4.

Comment: Problem located: expect a CTAN update to go today!

Comment: Okay, perfect!  I'll keep an eye out for it.  Thanks for your quick response.